# How to get association_ids before update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm making a plugin for redmine and I don't want to modify its code.

Redmine has a class named `Member` which has many `Role`.

When `Member` is updated, the roles are modified. I want to make a callback `after_update` or `around_update` but I'm not being able to get the `role_ids` before the update.

The role ids are being modified using `member.role_ids =`.

I guess I can try to override the method `role_ids=` in `Member` but I'm not sure what's the impact of that when an update to Redmine is available.

RoR 3.2.11
Redmine 2.2.1

Comment: what does it mean ```but I'm not being able``` what is the code that you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the instance of the `Member` class you could extend it at runtime and override the role_ids method:

```
module ExtendedMember
  def role_ids=(value)
    # do something (you can even call super)
  end
end

@member = Member.new
@member.extend ExtendedMember
@member.role_ids = [1,2,3] # will call the role_ids method of ExtendedMember

# ...
```

Beware that your method will only be available for this one instance of the `Member` class!